# show that $a<b$ implies to $\sqrt{a}<\sqrt{b}, a \geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, real-numbers

Let us take $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ where $b>a\geq 0$ I'd like to know why $\sqrt{a}<\sqrt{b}$

What I tried:

$\mathbb{R}=S/\sim$ where $S$ is the set of cauchy rational sequencies, we have that:

$a<b$ for $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ then:

there exists $r,n_0$ such that $b_n-a_n \geq r$ for all $n \geq n_0$ with $a$=$[(a_n)]$ and $b=[(b_n)]$

the problem is how I'd get $\sqrt{a}$ and $\sqrt{b}$ is terms of equivalence class to go on, I'd define $\sqrt{a}=[(\sqrt{a_n})]$ but it'd cover sequences which are not rational. Is there any way to go on using $\mathbb{R}=S/\sim$?

Comment: There is exist some rational $c$ such that $\sqrt{a} < c < \sqrt{b}$. Can you take it from there?

Comment: where do you know that from

Comment: You can prove this. It may prove instructive if you aren't given it. Start by looking at $a < c^2 <b$ and figuring out why such a $c$ must exist. Note the midpoint between $a$ and $b$ is going to be rational as well so it gives you something to aim for with your choice in $c$.

Comment: Once you define things you have defined them.  I see no reason once stating that that $a < b$ to try to reduce either to Cauchy sequences so that $b_n-a_n >0$.  If $0\le a < b$ then $\sqrt a$ and $\sqrt b$ exist.  And you have three choices.  Either $\sqrt a < \sqrt b$ or $\sqrt a = \sqrt b$ or $\sqrt a > \sqrt b$.  Exactly one of them must be true.  Two of them lead to contradictions.  One of them doesn't.  The one that doesn't has to be the one that is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**HINT**

Since $b > a \geq 0$, we can proceed as follows

\begin{align*}
b - a = (\sqrt{b})^{2} - (\sqrt{a})^{2} = (\sqrt{b} + \sqrt{a})(\sqrt{b} - \sqrt{a}) > 0
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 0):

Either $\sqrt{a} < \sqrt{b}$, $\sqrt{a} = \sqrt{b}$ or $\sqrt{a} > \sqrt{b}$. In the first case we are done. In the other cases, we can square both sides and obtain $a=b$ or $a>b$ which both contradict our assumption of $a<b$.

More generally, many algebraic properties of the reals can be shown without appealing to Cauchy sequences, as long as certain basic facts about the reals have been shown (namely that it is a Dedekind-complete ordered field).

Comment: is it not common demonstrante inequations/equations having irrational numbers by cauchy sequences?

Comment: No. I think of the relation between reals and Cauchy sequences like this: We want real numbers to be a set of objects with some operations (plus, minus, times, division) and an order satisfying some properties (being a complete ordered field). Cauchy sequences serve as one example (called a "model" in the jargon) with these properties, but there are others. E.g. Dedekind cuts. A theorem says that all properties of the reals (up to some details) can be deduced independently of the model. That's why we rarely need Cauchy sequences for facts like your question.